# Chrome Developer tools orange box

Tags: html, css

I know that the orange box in developer tools represents margin but when I do margin: 0; to a block element it is still there (the orange box), I know that block element takes full width always and doesn't allow other elements on the same row/line, so what is that orange box which takes full width (of what's left of the width)? Is it just margin that you cannot remove or is it something else?

Comment: can you share a bit of codes about what you want to do?

Comment: Please share what exactly you have done so that we can help you.

Comment: screenshot: https://prnt.sc/xpguhc 
my question is: why does it show the orange part in the developer tools even tho the margin is set to 0? Is it just margin that you cannot remove for block elements or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing about margin, its all about when you give `display:block` your elements wants to `width:100%` but you give `width:200px` so this orange box occured to keep the whole line.

İf you remove this orange box you can give your element `display:inline-block;` but at this time your another elements can come next to the element you are using. If you want to prevent this, you can make a container class and give it `width:100%;`.